# CString results in ? when trying to assign _variant_t.bstrVal which contains russian chars

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings

I am working on a desktop application.
I am facing this problem.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot when this code runs it assigns Russian string to CString but its value gets corrupted.

```
CString csField = vField.bstrVal;
```

The bstrVal contains Створное O^Л.
When I assign it to CString it becomes ??s.

Comment: Educated guess: you are building an ANSI build, so `CString` is a narrow string and the assignment involves Unicode to ANSI conversion. But the system codepage is not Cyrillic, so those Unicode characters are not representable in it. Ideally, switch to a Unicode build.

Comment: Go to your project settings, and add the [_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#remarks-8) preprocessor symbol. Recompile. The error list will now contain a list of all potential bugs.

Comment: Looks like `bstrVal` is a unicode and `csField` a narrow string. This will work only if the system codepage is Cyrillic, and `bstrVal` contains only characters that do exist in the Cyrrilic ANSI codepage. Unfortunately the system codepage can be set only globally, not per application. See a related answer in the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872812/visualisation-of-uft-8-polish-not-working-properly/49880640#49880640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Remember**: When this problem occurs, first check the current culture or locale.

The answer to the problem is:

> There was a line in my code which was setting current culture to
>   Invariant culture.

The strange thing I could not understand is when I get the current locale by **setLocale(LC_ALL, NULL)** it was returning the same thing irrespective of my current culture was **Russian** or **Invariant**.

To solve this problem I removed that code and now it's working fine.

```
//Thread::CurrentThread->CurrentCulture = gcnew CultureInfo("");
```